# Multiple submissions in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working on synchronizer token pattern in Spring MVC. My problem is in controller when first request is already submitted and second is submitted, I lose my first request. I actually want to ignore my second request and continue processing for first request so response for first request is shown to the user, with Struts2 we can achieve this by using TokenSessionStoreInterceptor but how we do this in Spring MVC?